# Reorder the UITableViewCells when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a problem in `UITableViewController` with static cells, which is each time we scroll down or up, the created cell is added to the lowest layer in depth, so if the cell has a view larger than the cell size, the view will be covered by the next cell
[image]

I want to show a tooltip when the user press the info button, and the tooltip for sure will be larger than the cell size, so it will be covered by the next cell.

I use [AMPopTip](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip) for the tooltips

Answer (score 0):

What view are you trying to show the AMPopTip in? Ran a quick test, and this seems to work (in a UITableViewController class):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let rectOfCell = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
    let rectOfCellInSuperview = tableView.convert(rectOfCell, to: tableView.superview)
    popTip.showText("test \(indexPath)", direction: .down, maxWidth: 200, in: self.view, fromFrame: CGRect(x: rectOfCellInSuperview.size.width / 2, y: rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y + tableView.contentOffset.y + rectOfCellInSuperview.size.height / 2, width: 1, height: 1))

}
```

Edit: whoops, forgot to account for scroll offsets - fixed... D'oh!

Comment: can you explain why you are adding tableView.contentOffset.y to calculate the frame the tooltip will point to?